# tf14092 a parent of this item has a pending delete which must be checked in first

Tags: tfs

I am trying to load entites to my asp.net web api using DataBaseFirst Approach .

After I run this command in my Package Manager:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myserver;Database=myDatabase;UID=user;PWD=pass;" 
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

I get the Models Folder with entities and the `DbContext`, but in the process I get many errors of this type:

> tf14092 : impossible to modify the element  x.  a parent of this item has a pending delete which must be checked in first

[image: error screanshot]
What does this error means? How to fix it?

Comment: According to the error you have a pending delete which you need to check into TFS before you can make further changes to the project. There seem to be a lot of results when googling for this error.

Comment: I m new to TFS , could you clear it more please .
what is a pending delete in TFS ?
the element x is a new entity generated by database first approach , how it  could have a pending delete

Comment: I don't know TFS at all, I just googled the error. I recommend doing the same.

Comment: Hi A.HADDAD, Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: hi, i will try it as soon as possible since i don't have all priveleges in TFS , i need to ask the admin who is my boss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot, there is a `x` symbol with wwwroot folder.

First check to see if you have pending deletes. Kind like below in pending change and source control explorer

[image]

[image]

If there are , choose to check in or undo pending change/delete. Then check again.

If there are not any pending delete. Try to [clear TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) and restart Visual Studio. Which may do the trick.

Comment: Actually you are right , but the folder that made the issue was named models for me , it was on pending delete which triggerd the issue when i tryied to create that folder again with database first approach as described above .